# Closing a VF popup window from a wordpress site

Tags: javascript, force.com-sites, popup

I have a Visualforce page exposed through force.com site. This page is exposed through an iframe in a popup (in a wordpress site). The page has some information to fill up and on the click of submit it saves in Salesforce. Also I want to close this popup once it is submitted. I tried using window.parent.close(); and window.parent.refresh() but it doesn't work.

Here is how my code looks like  -

```
<script>

function validate()
{
validations //javascript validations
saveData(); //saves in database
window.parent.close();
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't close the iframe popup from itself, you need to call a method on the parent that closes the current popup, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382769/how-to-close-iframe-popup-in-html)